# Change all MongoDB object ids in a MongoDB document/object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB object like this:

```
  _id: 5d285b1b05765e16e843136f
  projectName: 'XXX'
  projectType: 'XX',
  projectAlternatives:
  [ { _id: 5ccc5f66c4ae03001706a5a4,
       alternativeActors: [
       {_id: ...},{_id: ...}]
     ,},
    { ...},
  ],
  projectActors:
  [ { _id: 5ccc5fa1c4ae03001706a5a9,
       ... },
    { _id: 5ccc5fa6c4ae03001706a5af,
       ...},
  ]
  ...
```

I want to duplicate this object and save in the database. So I have to change all the ObjectID to a new one.

I used

```
object._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
object.isNew = true
```

to renew the `_id`, however, it can only renew the ObjectID of the main document. There are more nested objects arrays and the objectID of each sub-document also need to change.

So how can I do to update all the ObjectID `_id` to new ones

Comment: Do you want to keep the old docs and create the duplicates, or do you want to completely replace with the duplicates

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I want to keep the old docs and create the duplicates

Answer (score 1):

you can use below line

_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: new ObjectID() }

in sub document schema

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. The ObjectID just didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can first loop over each object to just change the user id to a new object id. So considering an array of object can do something like this:

```
someArray.forEach((user) => {
 delete user._id;
})

db.collection.insertMany(someArray);
```

Just keep the Sync & Async in mind while doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to achieve this. For every object, check type of all its field.

Traverse on all the keys of object using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

1. If field is _id : replace with new _id
2. If field is an object : call the recursive function on the field itself.
3. If field is an array : call the recursive function on all its elements.

Try this:

```
function replaceObjectIds(object){
    //check if its an object
    if(typeof object === 'object'){

        Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
            //if object[key] is an array 
            if (Array.isArray(object[key]){
                object[key] = object[key].map(obj =>{
                    return replaceObjectIds(obj);
                })
            }
            //if object[key] is an object 
            else if (typeof object[key] === 'object'){
                object[key] = replaceObjectIds(object[key])
            }
            //if object[key] is an ObjectId,  replace it 
            else if(key == _id){
                object._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
            }
        })
    }
    return object;
}

//call this function for every document of your collection, and save it
db.collection_name.find({}).forEach(doc => {
    doc = replaceObjectIds(doc)
    doc.save();
})
```